# Get IP From Google

Tags: vb.net, ip, google-search

I'm writing an app in vb.net that needs public IP address in text only format. I'd knew there is lots of site that give you your IP in text format. But where is always a chance of being closed or getting out of service. But the Google will not ever stop! Now I want to get my ip from google searching. For example if you search "my ip" in google it will bring your ip like this:
[Sample of search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IobG.png)
Is anyway to get IP from Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys but I found a way:
At first import some namespaces:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Now lets write a function:

```
Dim client As New WebClient
Dim To_Match As String = "<div class=""_h4c _rGd vk_h"">(.*)"
Dim recived As String = client.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=my+ip")
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(recived, To_Match)
Dim text_with_divs As String = m.Groups(1).Value
Dim finalize As String() = text_with_divs.Split("<")
Return finalize(0)
```

It's now working and live!

Answer (score 1):

Hard-coded Div Class names make me a bit nervous because they can easily change at any time, so, I expanded on Hirod Behnam's example a little bit.

I removed the Div Class pattern, replacing it with a simpler IP address search, and it'll return only the first one found, which for this search, should be the first one shown on the page (your external IP).

That also removed the need for splitting the results into the array, and those related vars. I also simplified the Google search string to the bare minimum.

It'd still probably be a nice touch to include a timeout or two for the .DownloadString() and the .Match() respectively, if speed is of the essence.

```
Private Function GetExternalIP() As String

Dim m As Match = Match.Empty

Try

    Dim wClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim strURL As String = wClient.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip")
    Dim strPattern As String = "\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b"

    ' Look for the IP
     m = Regex.Match(strURL, strPattern)

Catch ex As Exception
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("GetExternalIP Error: {0}", ex.Message))
End Try

' Failed getting the IP
If m.Success = False Then Return "IP: N/A"

' Got the IP
Return m.value

End Function
```